# How To implement TouchPad with First person camera controller in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch, game-engine

I have created my own InputAdapter so I can use it in my 3D game app ,
it consists mainly of TouchPad and First person camera controller and calculate if the touch event hits the touchpad or the screen so i can pass the touch event to the correct listener , here is the code:

```
 package com.mygdx.game.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.FirstPersonCameraController;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad;


public class MainController extends InputAdapter {
    private float YAxis = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    private PerspectiveCamera camera;
    private FirstPersonCameraController cameraController;
    private Stage stage;
    private int padPointer = -1;
    private int camPointer = -1;
    private final String TAG = "TOUCH_EVENT";


    public MainController(PerspectiveCamera camera, Stage stage) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.stage = stage;

        cameraController = new FirstPersonCameraController(this.camera);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        Actor actor = stage.hit(screenX, YAxis - screenY, true);
        if (actor != null && actor instanceof Touchpad) {
            padPointer = pointer;
            stage.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pad down pointer = " + pointer);

            return true;
        } else {

            camPointer = pointer;
            cameraController.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);

            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "camera down pointer = " + pointer);
            return true;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        if (pointer == padPointer) {
            stage.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pad dragging pointer = "+pointer);

            return true;
        }

        if (pointer == camPointer) {
            cameraController.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "camera dragging pointer = " + pointer);

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {



        if (pointer == camPointer) {
            camPointer =-1;
            cameraController.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "camera up pointer = " + pointer);
            return true;
        }
        if (pointer == padPointer) {
            padPointer = -1;
            stage.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pad up pointer = " + pointer);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void update() {
        cameraController.update();
        stage.draw();
    }

    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

this is a show case of my problem:

case 1: **1st** finger on **touchpad** and then **2nd** finger on the **screen**

result : can move the touchpad but can't move the screen and when moving the touchpad the screen moves too !!

case 2: **1st** finger on **screen** and then **2nd** finger on **touchpad**

result : it works perfectly and the touchpad and the screen moves independently each according to its finger (pointer).

so how to solve the first case to become like the second one which is the perfect for me.
I don't know how come the cameraController moves according to the first pointer even though it does't depend on it !?.

Comment: did you solve this mate?